# What does Dr. Ana Stelline know in the movie Blade Runner 2049?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

Maybe I am a little bit slow on the uptake but I am not sure whether Dr. Ana Stelline (Carla Juri) from *Blade Runner 2049* was aware that she is a child of a replicant and a human being.

Comment: It's not clear that she's the child of a human being.

Comment: Do you mean the possibility that Deckard is a replicant too?

Comment: Yes, whether Deckard is human or replicant has been in question for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only just seen the movie so I haven't had multiple viewings to reinforce anything but speaking from first impressions, I believe that she does know her past.

In talking with K he asks her if any of the implanted memories are someone's real memories and she indicated that using real memories is illegal.  But, as it turns out, the memory of the horse is actually her memory.  I believe that she actually used the memory in blade runners as a form or protection -- if one of them actually started hunting her, he might run across the date on the tree and associate with the date on the horse just as K did (interestingly, when I saw K's reaction to the date and his flashback to the horse -- my first thought was "Trojan horse").  Then, having made that association he might come to think that he is the missing child, just as K did throwing him off her trail.

When K came to her about his memory and she realized what memory he was having she seemed visibly shaken, as if things had gotten much too close to home and perhaps her ruse might not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And why did she lie to K regarding his false memories?

Comment: She wanted him to believe that they were really his memories so that he would believe that he was the child.

Comment: Of course. But why? Just only because she thought that K would feel better with that false information

Comment: I have a feeling that I am not understanding exactly what you are asking about but basically my thinking is this: K's a blade runner -- if the evidence he's tracking leads him to her, she could be killed (or worse).  If the evidence he's tracking leads him to him, she's safe.  So she wants him to believe that he's the child replicant so he won't continue searching and possibly determine that it is her.

Comment: Ana didn't lie to K: She said "Someone lived those memories" - she didn't say that it was his natural memories, only that they come from someone that had a real childhood. K interpreted it wrong, believing that they were his.